# Only match if surrounded by quotes

Tags: regex

I need to match **words** of certain criteria, but *only* if they are within quotes*. I'd wish to do this via Regex.

> *I think there's a "jQuery plugin for that". Google for jQuery basic arithmetic plugin.*

Let's say I have the above text as the subject of a Regex search, and I'd wish to find the word *"plugin"*, **if it is inside quotes**. I do not need to match the second *"plugin"* word at the end of the sentence, since it's not within quotes, but (edit) I do need to match multiple occurrences of *"plugin"*, were they enclosed by quotes (even if there are multiple occurrences inside a *single* quotation block).

With a working expression, the following words (highlighted with bold text) should be matched:

> *I think there's a "jQuery **plugin** for that". Google for jQuery basic arithmetic plugin.*

I have a theoretical solution that would use a positive lookahead to determine if there is an even or odd number of quotes, and match the word if that number is odd.

What regular expression should I use to accomplish this?

**double quotes only*

---

I use this expression to match words that are *not* surrounded with quotes, following a very similar logic:

```
\bplugin\b(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Comment: The one coming with JavaScript and PHP. I need code that works on both, that is, no lookbehinds.

Comment: @stribizhev No, that question would like to include the entire quotation if it is a match. I need to return a _certain_ word from within the quotation, **not the entire quotation itself**. EDIT: the referenced question's answer suggests an approach using capturing groups (if I understand it right). I'm interested in doing a positive lookahead, so it can be done in one run instead of a second, to extract.

Comment: What about if there is a line break inside the quotes?

Comment: @dawg Line break should be treated as simple whitespace. Line breaks inside quotes should not affect the outcome.

Comment: How do you define "inside"? The posted solutions will match if there is a double quote to the left and another to the right, but "inside"  implies you  need to pair up quotes, so that *"my" plugin beats "your" plugin* should not match on the first *plugin*, even though it is technically "between" quotes; only *my* and *your* are "inside" quotes. Also, if this is an issue, do we need to worry about the corner case of unpaired quotes? What about escaped quotes?

Comment: I am not sure, but what about `"\S[^"]*(plugin)"|"(plugin)[^"]*\S"|"\S[^"]*(plugin)[^"]*\S"|"(plugin)"`? Please have a look at https://regex101.com/r/yQ7oB5/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple regex like this:

```
".*?(plugin).*?"
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM1qO9/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Unfortunately, this matches the entire quotation. I only need to match a given word from within the quotation, not the entire thing.

Comment: @JánosWeisz the regex matches the entire quotation, but if you want to capture the word just surround plugin with parentheses. You can see it in the working demo

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
"[^"]*(plugin)[^"]*"


" : This looks for a double quote.
[^"]* : Followed by 0 or more characters that are not double quotes.
(plugin) : Followed by the text you are looking for inside its own subgroup
[^"]* : Followed by 0 or more characters that are not double quotes.
" : Followed by a double quote
```

Comment: Very close, but I do not need to match everything inside quotes, only the a given word, in this example, "plugin". I have edited my answer to include a second blockquote, with the matched words in bold.

Comment: @JánosWeisz You can easily create a sub-group for the matched text. Doesn't that give you what you need?

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, it would make sense to use a capturing group, right?

Comment: @JánosWeisz Exactly, that's what I am talking about

Comment: Although the question did not explicitly mention this, AFAIK this solution would be unable to extract _all_ matches, unless I'm missing something. This was the original reason I tended to prefer a positive lookahead based solution.